# Error message with the function melt

Tags: r, reshape2

I am new to R and I really need your help. I stumped for days on this matter but no clue. I need to convert a wide data set into the long format. I have 63 observations and 146 variables. That means I will end up with 9072 rows.

The long data set I am trying to get should look like this:

Participant group Item  ratings
1             1     1       2
1             1     2       3
                   144
etc..

Here is the structure of the data set.

```
str (age_ratings_wide)
'data.frame':   63 obs. of  146 variables:
 $ participant    : Factor w/ 63 levels "E1","E10","E11",..: 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 ...
 $ group          : Factor w/ 3 levels "1-6","7-13","NS": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ M1_5_adv_g1    : int  2 4 5 5 4 5 5 5 4 5 ...
 $ M1_17_adv_g2   : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...

  [list output truncated]
```

The problem is that I first managed to convert it as I want but failed to save. Then it stopped working for me. I use RStudio and reshape2 with melt as a function.Here is my command line:

```
age_ratings_long <-melt(age_ratings_wide[c(3:146)],id.vars = c("participant","group"),value.name = "ratings",varaible.name="item")
```

> Error: id variables not found in data: participant, group

I continue to get this error message even when I tried to shorten the number of columns I want to stack up.

Kholoud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
age_ratings_long = melt(age_ratings_wide,id.vars=c("participant","group"))
```

If this run, I think you have deleted your `id.vars` with `age_ratings_wide[c(3:146)]` command.

Comment: Thanks! Yes! that ran for me. It is strange that id.vars gets deleted when specifying the columns to be converted. Does this mean? I have to always avoid the [c(x:x)] command?

Comment: No it uses this two columns to "pivot" table. For `[c(x:x)]` Yep exaclty :). Please click on the tick if you're OK (on the left) ;)